# I think there may be an error in this question: f:Z->N f(x)=|x|-4 find the image of the function

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

However, for a relation between two sets to be defined as a function, for every a which belongs to A, f(a)=b where b belongs to B.

In this question A is defined to be Z (Where Z is all natural numbers, negative natural numbers and 0) and B is defined to be N(Where N is all natural numbers).

But for the value f(4)=|4|-4=0 0 does not belong in N.

This is a contradiction to the definition of a function because the function has a value that it cannot assign to an object in N by its own definition.

Am I mistaken? 
[image: Here is an image for refrence]

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Where you said groups, I think you meant sets

Comment: Very true, sorry, language barrier.

Comment: May  the function be $f(x)=|x-4|$?

Comment: I've added a direct screenshot from the assignment to the body of the post for reference.

Answer (score 4):

The definition of $\Bbb N$ may or may not include $0$ depending on where on Earth you live, so your counterexample is not necessarily solid.

However, anyone will agree that $\Bbb N$ consists of non-negative integers only, with or without $0$, so $f(0)=-4$ does provide an example showing that there is a problem.

Comment: Yup, very true. However, from previous consultations with this professor, he does not consider 0 to belong to N. But yea, f(3), f(2),f(1) and so on are all outside of the range.